# How to handle FacebookOAuthException in restFB and Java?

Tags: java, restfb

When usign the RestFB SDK and a wrong or expired token when authenticating, the application crashes. It can't be handled by a try/catch block. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FacebookClient facebookClient = null;
    String _pageAccessToken = "0000";

    if (!"".equals(_pageAccessToken)) {
        try{
            facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(_pageAccessToken, Version.VERSION_18_0);
        }catch (FacebookOAuthException ex1) {
            String msg = "Authentication error ...";
        }catch (Exception ex2){
            String msg= "Authentication error ...";
        }catch (Throwable th1){
            String msg= "Authentication error ...";
        }

    }
}
```

Message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: The access token could not be decrypted (code 190, subcode null) 'null - null'
at com.restfb.exception.generator.DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator.java:181)
at com.restfb.exception.generator.DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator.java:65)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:850)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:766)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:722)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.publish(DefaultFacebookClient.java:353)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.publish(DefaultFacebookClient.java:373)
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>2023.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How to prevent the app from crashing?

Comment: Because you try to use a bad access token, Facebook sends an error of Type OAuthException. So RestFB converts this in a FacebookOAuthException. So far everythin is right. You and your application has to handle this situation and do something, because there is no autoheal for bad access tokens. Maybe you have to show some dialog or somehting. That's what you can do in your exception handling.